# How do I extract text from string between 2 words in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I would like to get the text between 2 words from a string.
the `GROUP TITLE` is between `GROUP TITLE` and `DURATION`
`Group Title:  Goal Setting Duration: 60 minute`
I would like the results to be in a separate column and `DURATION` in another column.

I am using the following, but its not a consistent position in the string and i get part of additional text when i use the following

```
CASE WHEN A.NOTE_TEXT like 'Group Title:%' 
then SUBSTR(A.NOTE_TEXT,INSTR(A.NOTE_TEXT,'Group Title:',1),55) END AS GROUP_TITLE,*
```

My results would look like

```
GROUP TITLE                   |  DURATION
Group Title: Goal Setting     |  Duration: 60 minutes      
Group Title: Mood Management  |  Duration: 90 minutes
```

How can i get only the text for `GROUP TITLE` column from `GROUP TITLE: TITLE OF GROUP REPORT` to `DURATION`?

any help would be appreciated. 
thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for.  The regex uses a capturing group to "remember" what is between the anchoring text and return it.

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select 'Group Title: Goal Setting Duration: 60 minutes'    from dual union all
     select 'Group Title: Mood Management Duration: 90 minutes' from dual
   )
   select regexp_substr(str, 'Group Title:\s(.*?)\sDuration.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) "GROUP TITLE",
          regexp_substr(str, '.*Duration:\s(.*?)( |$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) "DURATION"
   from tbl;

GROUP TITLE        DURATION
-----------------  -----------------
Goal Setting       60 minutes
Mood Management    90 minutes

SQL>
```

EDIT  These regex's delimit on the colon only in case the headings ever change:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '.*:\s(.*?)\s.*:.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) "GROUP TITLE",
       regexp_substr(str, '.*:\s(.*?)( |$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) "DURATION"
from tbl;
```

EDIT AGAIN Taking it to the next step, if you consider this is really just a delimited string, and the delimiter is a space-word-colon-space, capture and return the 2nd and 3rd groups of characters that are followed by a space-word-colon-space or the end of the line.

```
select regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)( \w+: |$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) "GROUP TITLE",
       regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)( \w+: |$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) "DURATION"
from tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below queries to get Group Title and Duration separately :

```
 select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(regexp_replace ('Group Title: Goal Setting ------------ Duration: 60 minutes','\-+','-'),'[^-]+',1,1),'[^:]+',1,2)  "Group Title" from dual;

 select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(regexp_replace ('Group Title: Goal Setting ------------ Duration: 60 minutes','\-+','-'),'[^-]+',1,2),'[^:]+',1,2) "Duration" from dual;
```

use below query if it expected as in below query:

```
select regexp_substr('Group Title: Discharge and Reintegration Duration: 60 minute','[^:]+',1,2) "Group Title" from dual

  select regexp_substr('Group Title: Discharge and Reintegration Duration: 60 minute','[^:]+',1,3)  "Group Title" from dual
```

Comment: that didnt work as i thought it would.  the actually text in the field is Group Title: Discharge and Reintegration  Duration: 60

Comment: I have edited my answer ...not sure if it expected like this for the text you posted

Comment: when i put my field in regexp_substr(regexp_substr(regexp_replace (GROUP_TITLE,'\-+','-'),'[^-]+',1,1),'[^:]+',1,2)  Group_Title2,     the results i get still pull in duration  Discharge and Reintegration  Duration.  how can i get rid of duration?

Comment: select regexp_substr('Group Title: Discharge and Reintegration Duration: 60 minute','[^:]+',1,2) "Group Title" from dual -- this is my new query

Comment: i am using the query provided above, thank you.  i do not know why it is picking up values for some fields and not for others   Group Title: Symptom Management  Duration: 60 Minutes  Symptom Management 
Group Title: Relaxation and Evening Planning                 Duration: 60 minutes 
 it is picking up the Symptom Management  but not the following one. the only thing i can think of is the spacing between the end of the title and duration.   regexp_substr(NOTE_TEXT, 'Group Title:\s(.*?)\sDuration.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) GROUP_TITLE_A,   how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

this worked perfectly!!

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select 'Group Title: Goal Setting Duration: 60 minutes'    from dual union all
     select 'Group Title: Mood Management Duration: 90 minutes' from dual
   )
   select regexp_substr(str, 'Group Title:\s(.*?)\sDuration.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) "GROUP TITLE",
          regexp_substr(str, '.*Duration:\s(.*?)( |$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) "DURATION"
   from tbl;

GROUP TITLE        DURATION
-----------------  -----------------
Goal Setting       60 minutes
Mood Management    90 minutes

SQL>
```

Comment: Something to think about.  If your headings in the strings change, you'll have to change this code. Change the regex's to still work without having to use hardcoded headings, thus saving coding changes down the road.

Comment: i am using the query provided above, thank you. i do not know why it is picking up values for some fields and not for others Group Title: Symptom Management Duration: 60 Minutes Symptom Management Group Title: Relaxation and Evening Planning Duration: 60 minutes it is picking up the Symptom Management but not the following one. the only thing i can think of is the spacing between the end of the title and duration. regexp_substr(NOTE_TEXT, 'Group Title:\s(.*?)\sDuration.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) GROUP_TITLE_A, how do i fix this? –

Comment: Please update your post instead of posting in the comments as lack of formatting makes code hard to follow. A new post would be called for here possibly.